# REST GET api - what to return when resource not found

Tags: api, rest, jersey

I am using jersey to create rest api. I have GET api which returns xml or json representation of an object instance using JaXB. 
Everything is fine as long as I can get this instance based on id and return it. But when I don't find instance what should I return. I know 404 response has to be returned. But my method already returns a given type. So how do I setup 404 status is response?

Here is simplified version of my method

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public GameDAO getGameState(@PathParam("gameId") String gameId)
{
 //code to get game instance based on gameId
    if(game != null)
    {
        GameDAO d = new GameDAO(game);
        return d; //gets auto converted to xml or json
    }

    return null; //how to return not found response ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404 response is what you want, and I think the best way to get there is by throwing a "not found" WebApplicationException. Here's an example:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
```

There are plenty of ways to customize the error handling; you can find more details in the Jersey docs: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html

Comment: exactly what I wanted.Thanks